# URL that automatically logs user into Laravel 4 application

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I did not find help on Google because I don't know what keywords to search for. What I have tried did not bring results?

I have a Laravel 4 application with users that can log in.

In a partner's application where user also can login I want to show them a custom link and when they click on it they should be redirected to my app and automatically be logged in. So I need to pass the user credentials somehow through the URL of the link that I show them. Of course if someone gets hand on that URL he can log in as well so there needs to be some security (only valid for one login, valid only for a certain time... I don't know yet what's best practice here).

1. How is such thing called? I would like to do some more research.
2. How would I realize this? Are there any Laravel libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could make use of [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) for your scenario.

However, if you want a quick and simple solution, just do exactly what you described. Create a PartnerController with two methods. First one would be a service for your partner's app to ask for an authorization key which would be saved in a table. Then the second method could find the related user, login, and mark the authorization key as used.